# how to use ffmpeg in laravel to compress video file size

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

This is my first time using ffmpeg. I don't know if there is a tutorial on how to use ffmpeg in laravel to compress videos. Can someone please help me please?

```
   $pro=new User;
    $pro->company_name=$request->Business_name;
    $pro->cityandstate=$request->city;
    $pro->zipcode=$request->zip_code;
    $pro->phonenumber=$request->Phone_Number;
    $pro->website=$request->Website;

    $pro->tags=$request->tags;
    $pro->category=$request->categories;
    $pro->other=$request->other;

    $vid = $request->file('video');
      $filename = uniqid().$vid->getClientOriginalName();
      $path = $vid->storeAs(
'introvideo',
$filename);
      $location = public_path('/vids',$filename);
      $vid->move($location);
      $pro->intro_video= $filename;







    $pro->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find the documentation here. its not dificult to understand. 
[ffmpeg documentation from `laravel`](https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg)
if you have any thoughts just ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, ffmpg use terminal commands so if you can just it just like that. You have many options for that. Some example are:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Or see this documentation for Laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan

Comment: I am going show you my code. I want to know where do I add the ffmpeg? do I add it before the file saves to the database?

Comment: I`m not sure what you exactly want to achieve but if you want to compress video before store it use link that  @M.Maxime give you. It is very good package for ffpmeg. Just follow "redme.md"

Comment: I keep getting this error saying "Unable to load FFprobe" I am not sure what this means. Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you using package that @M.Maxime give you or with php shell. If you not using package you probably need ffprobe binary . See this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#ffmpeg  .

Comment: I am I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: How do I find the path to the FFProbe? Because I think its about a path thing maybe that's why it keeps saying "Unable to load FFProbe"

Comment: if you use linux the "whereis ffprobe" but should be on same place as ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Audio compress
    $inputAudio = public_path('/audio/myaudio.mp3');
    $outputAudio = public_path('/output/outputAudio.mp3');
    exec("ffmpeg -i $inputAudio -ab 64 $outputAudio");

    // Video compress
    $inputVideo = public_path('/audio/myvideo.mp4');
    $outputVideo = public_path('/output/outputVideo.mp4');
    exec("ffmpeg -i $inputVideo -ab 64 $outputVideo");
```